# Read from a file and insert the text into a table

Tags: java, sql

I am reading from a text file, then using that text to update a table. The code that I am having trouble with is the `String insertStatement`. I marked the problem location with a comment. Sorry it is a bit of a mess, but I wanted to include all that I have so far.

The file reads in fine and outputs fine I just need to figure out a way to insert the file information stored in the variable `line` into my table named `EMPLOYEE_COPY`.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class lab13 {
    {

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws SQLException {
        // The name of the file to open.
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@classdb.jccc.edu:1521:cisdb", "jpierc37", "jp2687");
        System.out.println("connected");
            String fileName = "enrollment.txt";
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            // This will reference one line at a time
            String line = null;
            try
            {        
                // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
                FileReader fileReader = 
                    new FileReader(fileName);

                // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                    new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                Statement insert = conn.createStatement();                 

                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    String insertStatement =
                            // This is the problem here.**********************************************
                            "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_COPY(Employee_ID, Name, Salary, Title)" +
                                    "VALUES(line)";
                    int count2 = insert.executeUpdate(insertStatement);
                    System.out.println("Inserted: " + count2);
                }   

                // Always close files.
                bufferedReader.close();       
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println(
                    "Unable to open file '");                
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(
                    "Error reading file '");                  
                // Or we could just do this: 
                // ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: You've asked to insert into the `Employee_ID, Name, Salary, Title` columns are simply providing a "line" as a single value?  Split the `line` into separate values and use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: What he said :)   Alos, you should be using PreparedStatements to avoid SQL injection - check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html